# Can not hear audio in 2.8

Tags: audio

Audio file uploaded to Video Editing, AV Sync on, but can not hear it? I just upgraded to 2.8 version, and I had never had any problems with audio on 2.79 version. Please help!

Resolved the problem by changing System -> Sound -> Audio Device from SDL to OpenAL.

Comment: Hi. If you have found a solution please use the answer box below instead of adding it into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was solved, but I would like to mention that the Audio Device that works can differ because I couldn't hear anything in the sequencer with OpenAL but when I changed it to SDL it worked for me. So if it's not working for you I think you should just try all Audio Devices.

Note: I'm on Linux Mint so it could have to do with your OS.