# why cant I hear the audio from an animation Im making?

Tags: audio

I've been working on an animation and once i switched it to a different computer the audio stopped working? Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not hear audio in 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149784/can-not-hear-audio-in-2-8)

Comment: it doesnt I tried switching it between the oprtions and trying to listen again  but I still cant hear